# How can I retrieve from my web map the resulting layer of a model execution stored in postgis and served with geoserver?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, geoserver

I have a web mapping application that executes a geographical model. The execution of the model may vary between 1 and 15 minutes.  The result of the model is a raster layer stored in a database. I need to retrieve the results of the model and display them in the web mapping application as soon as the result is ready. The application cannot be blocked while the model is executing.

The web application is written in Javascript and HTML. The web mapping engine is Openlayers 3. The model is written in R. The result of the model is a raster image and is directly stored in a PostGIS database when the model has finished its execution. The raster layer is served using geoserver using WMS 1.3.0. The web application, the R model and the database/geoserver are in different machines.

One solution would be to have a separate table in the database to store the last execution of the model, and keep polling the table from the web application until the value changes, then retrieve the result of the model and display it in the web application. I would not call this an elegant solution, and I am sure there must be a better solution.

I cannot show code because I have not started coding this functionality, it is still in the design phase.

Current solution (not actually a solution) is that the model has been executed a few times with different parameters and the results are stored in the database, so when the user thinks he is running the model he is actually switching layers. This is a temporary solution using three execution parameters with only three different values (meaning I have precalculated 27 layers), meant as a showcase, but the final product must be able to execute the model using 15 parameters with continuous values, so storing precalculated results of the model is not a viable solution. I need to be able to execute the model in real time and retrieve the results asyncronously.

Comment: Have you considered using the Web Processing Standard? - it allows you to execute asynchronous tasks and gives you a per task end point to poll.

Comment: @ian Thank you for the idea. However, after reading the docs of GeoServer 2.8 WPS, using the WPS standard involves rewriting the model for Geoserver, which is not an option for me. I only have power over the web application. I cannot make any changes to the R model, the geoserver ot the database.

Comment: you only need a thin wrapper to call out to the R model and then wait for the result

Comment: That is a very interesting and powerful approach. I did not know it existed. I will look further into it. Thank you @IanTurton.